# PHP retornando um JSON inválido

Tags: php, json

Estou trabalhando em um sistema onde todos os retornos do cURL serão salvos em um JSON no final da aplicação para ser utilizado pela galera do Mobile.

O sistema está todo em PHP, basicamente ele busca dados em uma API da footstats... Os dados retornados são utilizados no sistema, mas assim que eles vem no retorno da requisição, eu os salvo em um objeto...

O objeto está dentro do `public function __construct() {}`

Segue código do `construct`:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jsonGeral = new \stdClass();
        $this->jsonHeatmap = new \stdClass();
    }
```

A cada nova requisição os dados são salvos desta forma:

```
public function buscarJogo($idPartida)
    {
        $url = "partidas/".$idPartida;
        $response = $this->fazerCurl($url);
        $this->jsonGeral->dadosPartida = $response;
        $response = json_decode($response);
        return $response;
    }
```

o `$response`, já está vindo como Json, então eu apenas o coloco dentro do objeto.

No final, quando tudo o que era necessário já foi feito, eu faço a chamada para transformar tudo em Json:

```
public function gerarJsonGeral()
    {
        $jsonGeral = stripslashes(json_encode($this->jsonGeral));
        $data = date('d-m-Y-h-s-i');
        $arquivo = fopen("jsonGeral-".$data.".txt", 'w');
        if ($arquivo == false)
        {
            die('Não foi possível criar o arquivo.');
        }
        $texto = $jsonGeral;
        fwrite($arquivo, $texto);
        fclose($arquivo);

        return "jsonGeral-".$data.".txt";
    }
```

Ele irá gerar o arquivo, aparentemente ele estará correto, porém, quando tentar validar, vai dar um erro:

[image: Erro Json]

Já tentei modificar e ao invés de um objeto, deixar como `GLOBAL $json` e guardar tudo em forma de array, mas também não funcionou...

Não sei mais o que fazer e estou meio desesperado pra tentar fazer isto funcionar... Alguém consegue notar algum erro ou tem uma solução pra consertar isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acredito que o erro esteja nessa linha

```php
$jsonGeral = stripslashes(json_encode($this->jsonGeral));
```

## Atualização após o comentário

No caso, como `jsonGeral` se trata de um objeto, utilize apenas a função `json_encode`. Se deseja sanitizar os dados, trate-os antes da conversão para JSON, para não ter problemas.

Exemplo:

```
$jsonGeral = json_encode($this->jsonGeral);
```

A função `stripslashes` desfaz o efeito de `addslashes`. Esta última coloca uma `\` antes dos caracteres `'` ou `"`, ao passo que `stripslashes` retira essas barras.

Algumas vezes, o `JSON` gerado pode conter `\"`. Sendo assim, o uso da função `stripslashes` geraria um JSON inválido.

Exemplo:

```php
echo json_encode('Wallace"');
//resultado: ""Wallace\"""

echo stripslashes( json_encode('Wallace"') )
// resultado: ""Wallace"""
```

Se você quiser identificar o erro no `json`, pode usar a função `json_last_error` ou `json_last_error_msg`.

Assim:

```php
$json_errado = stripslashes( json_encode('Wallace"') );

json_decode($json_errado); // null

json_last_error_msg();
// "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"
```

Comment: Ele está retornando um erro:
`Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\footstats\src\Controller\CurlController.php on line 427` e o arquivo é gerado apenas com um `null` :/

Comment: Ah, já entendi o problema

Comment: E era exatamente este o problema... Brigadão pela rapidez da ajuda meu caro :D

Comment: Por nada, jovem. Fiz umas edições, caso queria debugar melhor alguns detalhes.